# How many IP-addresses my provider can provide me in total?

Tags: calculus, probability, computer-science

By tests (disconnect / reconnect over and over)
I have realized the size of the dynamic addresses of my provider.

Format:

$AAA.BB.X.YYY$

Now $AAA.BB$ are always the same. Only $X.YYY$ change where

$X$ can be $0, 1, 2$ or $3$ and

$YYY$ can be $0, 1,2,...235$

Now my question, how can I calculate the total number of possibilities? So I know how many IP addresses my provider can provide me in total (only different IP addresses count).

Is it done as easy as this: $4 \cdot 236 = 944$, so (only..) $944$ possible different IP addresses?

---

I'll ask an additional question here but I don't mind if it's ignored (because it hasn't much to do with maths): What's the usual amount of dynamic IP addresses provided to you? $944$, assuming my calculation is correct, is surprisingly very less for me.

Comment: The answer to your first question is Yes. You should probably post the second question in a different stack-exchange forum.

Comment: I don't dare to do that. They will shoot me down with their negative credits. Really evil and hatred community there, probably the worst one on stack exchange. Anyway, thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: Which community is that?

Comment: @barak manos I'm talking about "stack overflow".

Comment: I agree that there's a relatively large portion of smart@$$es there, but it still comes down to no more than a few percents, and the majority of users are still rather cooperative and helpful... In any case, I'm not so sure that stack-overflow is indeed the most suitable stack-exchange forum for your second question. Check [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) to find out what's best for your specific needs.

Comment: Oh wow I knew stack exchange is a large site but I didn't expect it was that large haha, so good! Thanks so much :D

Comment: Yes, I think that it originally started off as stack-overflow, and then expanded in the same format to many other topics. IMO, it is one of the three most important websites (along with Wikipedia and YouTube), in terms of knowledge sharing (and hence in general).